# Testing Android app in landscape using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 in Android Studio

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, landscape

My Android app is landscape-only. This means that all activity tags in `AndroidManifest.xml` have the attribute `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.

I am trying to write tests for a specific activity using a `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` subclass. When I run this test under `AndroidStudio` the app always appears in 'portrait' mode on the device that is used for testing.

Is there a way to force the activity being tested to start in landscape orientation?

I know I can call:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

in the **setUp** method, but that will switch the activity to landscape, not start it in landscape initially. It feels I somehow need to influence the `AndroidManifest.xml` generated by `gradle` for testing to include Activity declarations with the `screenOrientation="landscape"` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the test device, so that it has the screen in landscape orientation when it starts.

In Android Studio, its at AVD Manager > click on the edit pencil under actions > Click Landscape under startup size and orientation.